# Indirectly exported class not visible

Tags: flutter, dart, visibility, importerror, backendless

I'm having trouble using [the Backendless plugin for Flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/backendless_sdk).

I include

```dart
import 'package:backendless_sdk/backendless_sdk.dart';
```

(as per the instructions) and can then use e.g. `Backendless.UserService`. But if I try to generate a user to register, e.g.:

```dart
    var user = new BackendlessUser();
    user.setEmail("info@example.org");
    user.setPassword("password");
    Backendless.UserService.register(user);
```

I get an error `Undefined class 'BackendlessUser'` on the first line. This class is defined in `src/modules/user_service.dat`, which is exported by `src/modules/modules.dart`like this:

```dart
library modules;

export 'cache.dart';
...
export 'user_service.dart';
```

which in turn is imported by `backendless_sdk.dart` like this:

```dart
import 'package:backendless_sdk/src/modules/modules.dart';
```

I would have thought that it would get imported indirectly by the import of `backendless_sdk.dart`, but apparently not. When I import it explicitly (with the same import statement, but now in my own code and not just indirectly in `backendless_sdk.dart`), I get a warning `Don't import implementation files from another package`. But it's not an implementation file; it's exported as part of the public API (at least that's what I understand the `export` statement to mean).

The [Dart tutorial for creating packages](https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/create-library-packages) suggests to place the export statements directly under `lib`, not in `lib/src`, so I'm wondering whether this is an error in the structure of the plugin, or whether I'm doing something wrong.

I'd be grateful both for a solution to this particular problem and also for pointers to how I can better understand packages, libraries, imports and exports in dart; unfortunately I don't find [the language specification](https://dart.dev/guides/language/specifications/DartLangSpec-v2.2.pdf) particularly helpful in this regard.

(The error and the warning are the same whether I use `flutter analyze` or IntelliJ IDEA.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has been fixed in the 0.0.3 version of the plugin. Please update the backendless_sdk version in your pubspec.yaml.

You can include the only one import now:

```
import 'package:backendless_sdk/backendless_sdk.dart';
```

Please also note, that there are some changes in the syntax. So for your example you should use:

```
var user = new BackendlessUser()
  ..email = "info@example.org"
  ..password = "password";
Backendless.userService.register(user);
```

Comment: Great, thank you, that works! And the syntax is more convenient.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for using Flutter SDK and pointing out this issue.
It's indeed the problem in the structure of the plugin. The Backendless team is aware of it and this problem will be fixed in the next release of the plugin.
For now you can import explicitly and suppress the warning.